# Find closest value pairs and calculate mean in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

np.random.seed(5)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(100, 3)), 
                  columns=list('ABC'), 
                  index=['{}'.format(i) for i in range(100)])

ix = [(row, col) for row in range(df.shape[0]) for col in range(df.shape[1])]
for row, col in random.sample(ix, int(round(.1*len(ix)))):
    df.iat[row, col] = np.nan

df = df.mask(np.random.random(df.shape) < .05)  #insert 5% of NaNs  

df.head()

    A   B   C
0  99  78  61
1  16  73   8
2  62  27  30
3  80   7  76
4  15  53  80
```

If I want find closest value pairs from `columns A, B and C`, and calculate mean of pairs value as `column D`? How could I do that in Pandas? Thanks.

Since my real data has some `NaNs`, if some rows have only two values, then calculate their means as `columns D`, if some rows only has one value, then take that value in `column D`.

I have tried with calculating absolute value of each pairs, find smallest values from `columns diffAB, diffAC and diffBC`, then calculate means of smallest pairs means, but I think maybe there is better to do that.

```
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C']
df[cols]=df[cols].fillna(0)

df['diffAB'] = (df['A'] - df['B']).abs()
df['diffAC'] = (df['A'] - df['C']).abs()
df['diffBC'] = (df['B'] - df['C']).abs()
```

Update:

```
df['Count'] = df[['A', 'B', 'C']].apply(lambda x: sum(x.notnull()), axis=1)

if df['Count'] == 3:
    def meanFunc(row):
        minDiffPairIndex = np.argmin( [abs(row['A']-row['B']), abs(row['B']-row['C']), abs(row['C']-row['A']) ])      
        meanDict = {0: np.mean([row['A'], row['B']]), 1: np.mean([row['B'], row['C']]), 2: np.mean([row['C'], row['A']])}
        return meanDict[minDiffPairIndex]
if df['Count'] == 2:
    ...
```

Expected result:

```
    A   B   C   D
0  99  78  61  69.5
1  16  73   8   12
2  62  27  30  28.5
3  80   7  76   78
4  15  53  80  66.5
```

Comment: Expected output for this sample frame would be _great_... What "pairs" now?

Comment: I updated. Thanks. First step, I need to find nearest value pairs from each row, then calculate mean for each rows.

Comment: D is calculated as the mean of the row + the row it is closest to? For example, what is 69.5 the mean of?

Comment: It's the mean of 78 and 61, I updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you require an additional `column D` having the mean of the value pair which has the least difference among the three possible pairs: `(colA, colB), (colB, colC) and (colC, colA)`, following code should work:

**Updated:**

```
def meanFunc(row):    
    nonNanValues = [x for x in list(row) if str(x) != 'nan']
    numOfNonNaN = len(nonNanValues) 
    if(numOfNonNaN == 0): return 0
    if(numOfNonNaN == 1): return nonNanValues[0]
    if(numOfNonNaN == 2): return np.mean(nonNanValues)
    if(numOfNonNaN == 3):
        minDiffPairIndex = np.argmin( [abs(row['A']-row['B']), abs(row['B']-row['C']), abs(row['C']-row['A']) ])      
        meanDict = {0: np.mean([row['A'], row['B']]), 1: np.mean([row['B'], row['C']]), 2: np.mean([row['C'], row['A']])}
        return meanDict[minDiffPairIndex]

df['D'] = df.apply(meanFunc, axis=1)
```

Above code handles the `NaN` values in rows in the way that if all three values are `NaN` then `column D` has value `0`, if two values are `NaN` then non-NaN value is assigned to `column D` and if there exists exactly one `NaN` then the mean of remaining two is assigned to `column D`.

**Previous:**

```
def meanFunc(row):
    minDiffPairIndex = np.argmin( [abs(row['A']-row['B']), abs(row['B']-row['C']), abs(row['C']-row['A']) ])      
    meanDict = {0: np.mean([row['A'], row['B']]), 1: np.mean([row['B'], row['C']]), 2: np.mean([row['C'], row['A']])}
    return meanDict[minDiffPairIndex]

df['D'] = df.apply(meanFunc, axis=1)
```

Hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your help your solution works. One more question, if some rows have one two values, I want calculate their means as columns D, or if some rows only has one value, I want take that value in column D, how could I do that?

Comment: In case there are some `NaN` values in the dataframe, you can use `df.fillna(0)` to replace them with 0 and then (as a trivial solution) put if-else within meanFunc to check that if num of non-zero values == 3 then return what the above solution computes, if num == 2 return mean of these two non-zero values and if num == 1 then return that non-zero value as it is.

Comment: I updated my question and solutions, would you help me finish it?

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot. I use this if there are other columns: `df[['A', 'B', 'C']].apply(meanFunc, axis=1)`

Comment: Sorry, I have one more question: assuming column A doesn't has `nans`, and values from A have priority if absolute value between A and other column is more than 10, then take values from A, otherwise take their means. What I should do? I have tried following but got en error: `if(numOfNonNaN == 2):
        if np.abs(nonNanValues) >= 10:
            return row['A']
        else:
            return np.mean(nonNanValues)` Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

I'd use numpy here:

```
In [11]: x = df.values

In [12]: x.sort()

In [13]: (x[:, 1:] + x[:, :-1])/2
Out[13]:
array([[69.5, 88.5],
       [12. , 44.5],
       [28.5, 46. ],
       [41.5, 78. ],
       [34. , 66.5]])

In [14]: np.diff(x)
Out[14]:
array([[17, 21],
       [ 8, 57],
       [ 3, 32],
       [69,  4],
       [38, 27]])

In [15]: np.diff(x).argmin(axis=1)
Out[15]: array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1])

In [16]: ((x[:, 1:] + x[:, :-1])/2)[np.arange(len(x)), np.diff(x).argmin(axis=1)]
Out[16]: array([69.5, 12. , 28.5, 78. , 66.5])

In [17]: df["D"] = ((x[:, 1:] + x[:, :-1])/2)[np.arange(len(x)), np.diff(x).argmin(axis=1)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. But sorry I don't know how to integer your solution to my code. There are non-float columns in my real data.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the fastest way of doing this but it's very straightforward.

```
def func(x):
    a,b,c = x
    diffs = np.abs(np.array([a-b,a-c,b-c]))
    means = np.array([(a+b)/2,(a+c)/2,(b+c)/2])
    return means[diffs.argmin()]

df["D"] = df.apply(func,axis=1)
df.head()
```

Comment: Thanks. But how to related a, b, c with columns A, B and C? I use a = df['A']..., but I get a UnboundLocalError: ("local variable 'a' referenced before assignment", 'occurred at index 0')

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. If you just add my code between your df generation and the "df.head()" function it will just work. 
The relating part is the `a,b,c = x` part where it splits the input list into three independent variables. You can also do it as it is done in bazinga's answer but I think mine is cleaner.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question and solutions, please check.

Comment: Looking at the edit of your question I'm not sure you understood the concept of my or bazinga's answer. The idea is to define a function that handles all the logic you're describing and then apply this function to the whole dataset at once. Unless you need it for something else there's therefore no need for a **Count** column. Regarding your question in bazinga's answer: If _nonNanValues_ is a list the >=10 doesn't work for obvious reasons. That's probably also the error you receive.