# How to work out the average from a set of columns based on multiple conditions in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, average

I want to create a new column which shows the average based on multiple conditions. For the most part the new column should calculate the mean of the 3 columns. However, if the difference between A and B or B and C is greater than 10 then it should only use 2 values with the smallest difference.

For example if A = 2, B = 15 and C= 13 then the mean column should show 14. Because the difference between A and B is greater than 10 so the column should use B and C because they have the smallest difference to work out the mean.

I tried adding additional columns which determine the difference between A and B and for B and C. After that I used a conditional statement to create a list which appends the mean calculations based on the conditions and to then add the list as a column. However I get the error "Length of values does not match length of index".

This is the code used to create my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,20,size=(50, 3)), 
columns=list('ABC'))
```

My attempt at finding a solution:

```
df['diff_1'] = df['A'] - df['B']
df['diff_2'] = df['B'] - df['C']

average = []
for i in df['diff_1']:
    if i < -5:
        average.append(df[['A','B']].mean(axis=1))
    if i > 5:
        average.append(df[['A','B']].mean(axis=1))
    else:
        average.append(df[['A','B','C']].mean(axis=1))

df['average'] = average
```

I would then have repeated for diff_2 and remove duplicates however this gives me the aforementioned error:
"Length of values does not match length of index". So am I wondering if there is a more appropriate method.

I am expecting a column which shows the average of all three columns except for when the difference between A and B or B and C is greater than 10. If that is the case it should then calculate the mean using only 2 numbers with the lowest difference.

Comment: Here is compared also difference A with C columns ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for seelct values by conditions:

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,20,size=(50, 3)), 
columns=list('ABC'))

df['diff_ab'] = (df['A'] - df['B']).abs()
df['diff_bc'] = (df['B'] - df['C']).abs()
mindiff = df[['diff_ab','diff_bc']].min(axis=1)


ab = df[['A','B']].mean(axis=1)
bc = df[['B','C']].mean(axis=1)
abc = df[['A','B','C']].mean(axis=1)

N = 10
df['average1'] = np.select([(df['diff_ab'] > N) & mindiff.eq(df['diff_bc']),
                      (df['diff_bc'] > N) & mindiff.eq(df['diff_ab'])], 
                      [bc, ab],
                      default=abc)
```

Solution if need mean of minimal difference of any values per rows if any difference is less like 10:

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/54861589
x = df[['A','B','C']].values
x.sort()
mask = np.any(np.diff(x) > 10, axis=1)
a = ((x[:, 1:] + x[:, :-1])/2)[np.arange(len(x)), np.diff(x).argmin(axis=1)]
df["average2"] = np.where(mask, a, x.mean(axis=1))

print (df.head(10))

    A   B   C  diff_ab  diff_bc   average1   average2
0  13   2   2       11        0   2.000000   2.000000
1   6  17  19       11        2  18.000000  18.000000
2  10   1   0        9        1   3.666667   3.666667
3  17  15   9        2        6  13.666667  13.666667
4   0  14   0       14       14   7.000000   0.000000
5  15  19  14        4        5  16.000000  16.000000
6   4   0  16        4       16   2.000000   2.000000
7   4  17   3       13       14  10.500000   3.500000
8   2   7   2        5        5   3.666667   3.666667
9  15  16   7        1        9  12.666667  12.666667
```

Solution with check all columns used for count for verify/debug:

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,20,size=(50, 3)), 
columns=list('ABC'))

df['diff_ab'] = df['A'] - df['B']
df['diff_bc'] = df['B'] - df['C']
#if need difference in absolute values
#df['diff_ab'] = (df['A'] - df['B']).abs()
#df['diff_bc'] = (df['B'] - df['C']).abs()
df['mindiff'] = df[['diff_ab','diff_bc']].min(axis=1)

df['ab'] = df[['A','B']].mean(axis=1)
df['bc'] = df[['B','C']].mean(axis=1)
df['abc'] = df[['A','B','C']].mean(axis=1)

N = 10
df['average'] = np.select([(df['diff_ab'] > N) & df['mindiff'].eq(df['diff_bc']),
                           (df['diff_bc'] > N) & df['mindiff'].eq(df['diff_ab'])], 
                          [df['bc'], df['ab']], default=df['abc'])
```